# KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false

Tags: java, android, sdk, ads, adcolony

I am trying to set up AdColony on my Android App using Android Studio.

First time I launch the app and use the SDK it works fine. When I quit the app and comes back, it goes in a white screen and freezes.

here is the message it keeps outputting in logcat.

> KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false

does anyone has came across this before ?
thanks

Comment: I have seen this warning few times while interacting with samsung devices... Never seen the white screen like you mentioned. IMO, this message has nothing to do with AdColony sdk

Comment: I get the same message when I try to post a Flac audio file to Google's voice API

Comment: I am having this message on my application on Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo (5.1.1). My app does not use any Ad SDK. I am using NDK, and you ?

Comment: I'm getting this log while using Runtime to execute Ping command in android

Comment: Knox is a security product offered by Samsung for enterprise, it provides firewalls and other controlling features which companies used to restrict unwanted apps on their devices, it may possible that Knox (if active) may blocking adcolony requests because of which you're getting white screen.

Answer (score 0):

Knox is Samsung's enterprise security product:

https://www.samsungknox.com/en

You can expect to see this logging whenever you make an HTTP request. I think your freeze is probably unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Knox is a security product offered by Samsung for enterprise, it provides firewalls and other controlling features which companies used to restrict unwanted apps on their devices, it may possible that Knox (if active) may blocking adcolony requests because of which you're getting white screen.

Try it on a different samsung device, it should work!